# If else logic step error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I've made workflow in this pic below:

[image]

But these aren't true on output. soft.dev is include on VIP group, but in logic he pass "if" logic. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: will only Soft.Dev create items out from VIP group? what is VIP actually? SP group or AD group?

Comment: No, there's many people in VIP group. VIP is SP group. And it's like no simple solution about this

Comment: what are you talking about? Of course there is easy solution. I will post it now.

Comment: Uh oh, I've read this blog http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/12/15/spd2013-workflow-how-to-check-user-is-member-of-group.html 
And I'm not a programmer, so it difficult to me.

Answer (score 1):

For above issue for if else in workflow. 
please take one workflow variable to store people picker value and then check.

Comment: I've been tried that, not work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SharePoint Designer does not have any "Action" to find user in a SharePoint/Domain group like "VIP" in your case.

Possible options are

1. **Paid solutions** like Nintex Workflows that has a "Web Request" action to call an C# aspx page (could be an inline aspx in /_layouts/15 as well). This page can call SharePoint APIs and outputs true if user is in the group. The web request action reads the output and use that in an if/else condition to proceed further in the workflow. Example aspx page code

   ```
   <%@ Page language="c#" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
   <script language="c#" runat="server">
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           string u = Request["user"];
           string g = Request["group"];

           SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
           SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(u);
           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
           Response.Write(user.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(c => c.Name.Equals(g)));
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Response.Write(ex.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use REST calls in SP designer as described here http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/12/15/spd2013-workflow-how-to-check-user-is-member-of-group.html. There is a caveat as described in the article

> The Users Collection does not have a method for testing if a user exists.  So I've taken the shortcut and basically brute force the service and just try to retrieve a user.  If you try to request a user that doesn't exist in the collection, it will just error, and I just catch that error.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is enlight me. I must do research more about this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, The logic that you have written, will not check user in the VIP Sharepoint group. You need to write that logic,
You can use "call Webservice feature"  of SP2013 WF designer
Check whether user exists in that group and return result.
Hope it helps

Comment: I think so, after researching about this that wasn't able to check. Thank you for the info.